# What is the reason for using "Kt" suffix in Kotlin classes?

Tags: kotlin

I was trying to find more details about this decision in the Kotlin documentation but there is no section that "talks" about it. Does anyone know what drove the decision to use the "Kt" suffix in class names in Kotlin? Is it to avoid collision with Java class names, or is there more to it?

Comment: Yes, both have a different syntax. So it is a obvious choice to make. From what I have read till now, nothing of a story has been associated with the extension as of yet. But it easy for the team to attach one when things get popular :)

Comment: Maybe I don't really understand your question but I think .kt may come from the word Kotlin and what more appropriate suffix would you suggest? Kotlin code differs from java code (not entirely though but in most ways). I think it is logical for them to provide it with a different suffix

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unlike Java, Kotlin allows you to define functions that are not inside a class. But if you want Java to talk to Kotlin that becomes a problem. How to solve it? Convert those functions into static methods of a class named as the file with the "Kt" suffix

You can find more info about that in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions)

Comment: Whereas if you explicitly declare a class in Kotlin, it will not have `Kt` appended.