# Specifying Main class in pom.xml for spring boot projects in Kotlin

Tags: maven, spring-boot, kotlin

I have created a `Spring Boot` project using `Kotlin`. I would like to create a `.jar` file with all the dependencies so that I can run the application from the command line. The FQCN for the main class is: `com.example.Application.kt`. I have following configuration in my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.example.Application</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The application fails to start complaining that the mainClass was not found. Here is the sample exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Application
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am just attempting to learn Kotlin myself, but I suspect you may need to append `Kt` to the end of your classname. For example:

```
<manifest>
    <mainClass>com.example.ApplicationKt</mainClass>
</manifest>
```

Unrelated to Spring, I encountered this issue myself when attempting to build an executable JAR. If you unzip your JAR and look at the class files, I believe you will find an `ApplicationKt.class`.

If so, this is because you did not define the `main` function within a class.  In this scenario, Kotlin generates a static method belonging to a `<filename>Kt.class` version of your file. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45505308/3791964):

> Unlike Java, Kotlin allows you to define functions that are not inside a class. But if you want Java to talk to Kotlin that becomes a problem. How to solve it? Convert those functions into static methods of a class named as the file with the "Kt" suffix
>
> You can find more info about that in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other answers, I got this working with Spring Boot 2.4.2 and Maven

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>demoapi.DemoApiApplicationKt</mainClass>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

DemoApiApplicationKt

```kotlin
package demoapi

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApiApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApiApplication>(*args)
}
```

Comment: You are right. kt is needed to be added as answer by Miles_Dowe suggests. I had forgotten that I ever asked this question. Your answer reminded me to accept the original answer by Miles_Dowe

Answer (score 0):

Most likely exactly as the exception states: you are missing a class `Application` inside the package `com.example` having a companion object with a main method.

```
package com.example

import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
open class Application : ApplicationRunner {
    override fun run(args: ApplicationArguments) {
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it did not work. I understand the hack. As a matter of fact, you do not need `@SpringBootApplication`, just `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan`. However, with the newer version of `Spring Boot` and `Kotlin` this hack is no longer needed. The problem remains the same - **its not working** :`(

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same error. In my case, I had the main application in a different path than `src/main//kotlin`. Specifying that exact path in the `sourceDirectory` tag under the `build` tag solved my issue. This being said, you also need to append `Kt` to make your application class `ApplicationKt`. Below is the structure of my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/generated-source/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <mainClass>com.example.ApplicationKt</mainClass>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: In my case, if I remember correctly, the error popped up even with the default structure.